# How can I split a String when I'm splitting around the last character in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, split

I'm trying to split a String in two, then assign it to two variables.

When I split the String around one of the middle characters, it returns:

```rb
a, b = *"12x45".split("x")
>> a: "12"
>> b: "45"
```

When I split the String around the first character, it returns:

```rb
a, b = *"x2345".split("x")
>> a: ""
>> b: "2345"
```

But when I split the String around the last character, it returns:

```rb
a, b = *"1234x".split("x")
>> a: "1234"
>> b: nil
```

I would have expected `b` to be `""` instead of `nil`. Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: 1. You could add an additional `x` to the end of the string `a, b = "#{string}x".split('x')` 2. You could use conditional assignment after splitting the string `a, b = string.split('x')` followed by `b ||= ''`

Comment: `"1234x".split("x")` results in a one element array. You are trying to unpack into two values out of a single element array so `nil` is assigned to `b`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, while I almost always value your suggestions, that one, in my opinion, has been whopped with an ugly stick.

Comment: Are we to assume that `'x'` appears exactly once in the string?

Comment: I suggest you remove the "Solution" from your question.  Its a little confusing and also a little in poor taste as it takes from the work others put in to answer the question thoughtfully and in detail.  Questions should be questions, and answers should be answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split` takes an optional second parameter which limits the amount of splits. When this limit is set to -1 it behaves like " If limit is negative, it behaves the same as if limit was nil, meaning that there is no limit, and trailing empty substrings are included" (from the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-split)). So:

```
"1234x".split("x", -1) # => ["1234", ""]
```

Comment: Cool and educational!

Answer (score 6):

If there are at most two parts, you can also use [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#partition-method) which defaults to empty string if one part is "missing". As opposed to `split` it also returns the separator as the middle element: (you can assign it to `_` if you don't need it)

```
a, _, b = "12x45".partition("x")
a #=> "12"
b #=> "45"

a, _, b = "1234x".partition("x")
a #=> "1234"
b #=> ""

a, _, b = "x2345".partition("x")
a #=> ""
b #=> "2345"
```